# How can I change (and then reset) permissions for the root folder of my website?

Tags: javascript, sql, asp-classic

Here is my scenario...

1) Website is written in classic ASP with SQL database.
2) The owner can add/edit/delete pages via the CMS.
3) Not wanting to give write permissions to the root folder, I have created a folder /pages/ with write permissions.
4) When a new page is added, a folder is created in /pages/ and a master Index.asp file is copied to that new folder via javascript FSO.

This generates a URL like this: http://mydomain.com/pages/about_me/

What I would like to do is...

1) Change the permissions on the root folder, but not any child folders or files in the root,
2) Move the "master" file to the root using javascript FSO renaming it to the selected name (ie: about_me.asp),
3) Finally, reset the the permissions on the root folder.

Is this at all possible?

If not, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Think about this logically.  If your CMS is to perform this operation automatically then its IUSR account would need full permission on the root folder in order to change permissions!  All I can suggest is that you do give write permission to the root folder then deny it to everything within the root folder that you want to protect

Comment: That would be a consideration, but my current host will not allow changing permissions on files... only folders. Meaning, once r/w/x perms are on the root, I can reset all folders but any files in the root will remain r/w/x. Also, this is for a piece of CMS software. Try explaining that to a "regular Joe". ;) I need as much as possible to be done with the "click of a button".@John